# why doesn't this ReplaceAll work in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have

```
Table[{x1, 1, 2, 3}^i, {i, 0, 3}] /. x1 -> 1/2
```

But the following does not work, since x1 is not replaced with 1/2

```
Table[{x1, 1, 2, 3}^i, {i, 0, 3}] // Inverse /. x1 -> 1/2
```

Could anybody let me know why and how to fix it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at `TreeForm` to see how your expression is parsed.

`TreeForm@Hold[Table[{x1, 1, 2, 3}^i, {i, 0, 3}] // Inverse /. x1 -> 1/2]`
[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/treeform.png))</sub>

Everything after `//` is taken to be function head that is applied with Postfix notation. So you need some parentheses

```
(Table[{x1, 1, 2, 3}^i, {i, 0, 3}] // Inverse) /. x1 -> 1/2
```